# Getting relative paths in Vim

Tags: vim, relative-path

Say I am running Vim and pwd returns

```
/home/rafid/myproject
```

And say I am currently editing the file

```
/home/rafid/myproject/website/editpage.php
```

Is there any command that returns this for me?

```
website/editpage.php
```

That is, the path of the file relative to the current folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me :

```
:echo expand("%")
```

Comment: You can also use `<c-r>%` in insert mode to insert the current file name.

Comment: This does not always work and is dependent on how you initially opened the file. See @joeytwiddle 's answer to this question for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 36):

Although `expand('%')` often works, there are [rare occasions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525261/getting-relative-paths-in-vim#22856943) where it does not.  But you can force Vim to always present the relative path by calling `fnamemodify`:

```
:echo fnamemodify(expand("%"), ":~:.")
```

From the manual:

```
    :.      Reduce file name to be relative to current directory, if
            possible.  File name is unmodified if it is not below the
            current directory.
            For maximum shortness, use ":~:.".
```

The `:~` is optional.  It will reduce the path relative to your home folder if possible (`~/...`).  (Unfortunately that only works on *your* home; it won't turn `/home/fred` into `~fred` if you aren't logged in as `fred`.)

As Adam pointed out the comments, this can be **shortened** to:

```
:echo expand("%:~:.")
```

Reference: `:h expand<Tab>` and `:h fnamem<Tab>`

---

If you are limited for space (e.g. using this in your statusline), and can manage with "fuzzy" information about where the file is located, then check out `pathshorten()` which compresses folder names down to one character:

```
:echo pathshorten('~/.vim/autoload/myfile.vim')
~/.v/a/myfile.vim
```

Reference: `:h pathsh<Tab>`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Just for the record, looks like the modifiers can also be expanded directly using `:echo expand("%:~:.")`. More information can be found at `:help filename-modifiers`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I am working in vim and trying to execute a command inside a docker container (run a specific test file) so the absolute path won't work for me. Docker can't see the full path and my test runner inside the container throws an error because it can't find the file. `fnamemodify` worked perfectly!

Answer (score 11):

Another option would be to write a vim function. Here's my humble attempt:

```
function! Relpath(filename)
    let cwd = getcwd()
    let s = substitute(a:filename, l:cwd . "/" , "", "")
    return s
endfunction
```

You call Relpath with any full path name, and it will strip the current directory name from its argument.

For example, try `:echo Relpath(expand("%:p"))` (the `:p` modifier asks Vim to return the full path). Obviously, this is not necessary in your case, since `%` by itself returns relative path. However, it might come in handy in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

if you use autocmd to always set the current directory of the buffer that you are working on ( cd %:p:h ) then you can just type :cd

Comment: to the next person landing on this page - check out this vim tip for more details on setting cd with autocmd http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
:echo expand("%")
```

This is only working if you opened that file with a relative file:

```
for vi ./foo, expand("%") will be ./foo
```

but

```
for vi /tmp/foo expand("%") will be /tmp/foo
```

Comment: Not here.  If I am in `/tmp` and do `vi /tmp/foo` then Vim works out the relativepath, and `expand("%")` shows me `foo`.  **However** if I keep vim open in `/tmp` and do `:e /tmp/bar` **then** `expand("%")` will show the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

:args

This will give you the filename of the current file, for informational purposes.

Comment: Notice that I don't want the file name only, I want the relative path. So not just editpage.php, but 'website/editpage.php'.

Comment: Yes, it will take that into account.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be `:cd .` which seems to re-evaluate the path relative-ness. I agree this is very annoying though.